# Custom Query and Model in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a custom model with methods that connect to an existing DB and return data based on custom queries injected into Django. I am obviously having some problems with this, and am wondering if this is possible with my current approach. I feel like this is either a trivial question or I am misunderstanding something fundamental here. Here is my code so far:

```
from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class data_model(models.Field):
    description = "return and create data objects for visulaizations"

    def __init__(self, days, action):
        self.days = days
        self.action = action
        if(self.action == ""):
            self.action = "inspections"
            getVioPoints(self.action)

    def getVioPoints(self):
        #get points query here and get data from db 
        return self
```

Within `getVioPoints`, I want to create a query string - like what you would see in a PHP `$query = "select tuples where what I want = something"` type of situation. Then return the data in a way that my template views can access it like so:

```
<ul>
     {% for choice in data_returned %}
        <li> {% choice.title %} </li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any ideas? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: model have to be child of models.Model, try to read about django models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ and then think how to describe existing model as django model.

Comment: @zymud what about being able to return a JSON string so as to traverse with JS? I have read that part of the DOCs and am not sure if that gets at my problem. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Of course you can make custom query and put result into json, you can read about custom queries here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly, but this isn`t django-way - you just ignore orm layer and have to write all sql queries by yourself, I recommend you to create model, connect it to db and make queries through orm.

Comment: @zymud Great, that is what i was looking for. Throw it in an answer, i will give you a check mark. If you think my question was relevant, kindly give it the old thumbs up :), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom query and put result into json.

You can read about custom queries here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly,

but this isn`t django-way - you just ignore orm layer and have to write all sql queries by yourself, I recommend you to create model, connect it to db and make queries through orm.

Comment: But what if the query you want to make is not possible with the ORM?  I know about the raw() function however what if you need to make this query many times.  Is there not a way to set up a raw query as a function of the model class?